Cross Site Scripting issue in Apex Webservice while populating reponse
I have create a POST webservice to return CaseNumber for the CaseId provided in request.
The API is working fine, but Fortify is showing critical error for Cross Site Scripting.
Sample code
...
CaseResponseWrapper caseResponseWrapperInstance = new CaseResponseWrapper();
Case caseRecord = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId LIMIT 1];//We are getting caseId from the request body coming to Salesforce
caseResponseWrapperInstance.caseNumber = caseRecord.CaseNumber;
caseResponseWrapperInstance.Success = true;

RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(caseResponseWrapperInstance));//Getting Cross Site scripting error in Fortify
...
class CaseResponseWrapper
{
    String caseNumber;
    Boolean Sucess;
}

I tried various ways like String.escapeSingleQuotes() and create JSON using String variable instead of wrapper. Tried other solutions also but the error still persists.
I am finding solutions applicable on HTML, JS etc.
But not able to figure out any solution for Apex Cross Site Scripting issue.
Is anyone seen such issue?

I suggest this is a false positive. The CaseNumber string will get appropriately escaped automatically by the JSON.serialize. Mark it as a false positive and move on.

BTW, I assume your actual code is res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(...), right?
